# Magento 2.2:Fails Readiness Check due to Cron - Found non-writable path(s):

Tags: magento2, crontab, magento-cron, web-setup-wizard

Magento 2.2 Error from Updater Application Cron Script: Found non-writable path(s):

> /home/jon/as/.htaccess
>   /home/jon/as/.htaccess.sample
>   /home/jon/as/.php_cs.dist
>   /home/jon/as/.travis.yml
>   /home/jon/as/.user.ini